# How to Send sellect all command by ui automation c#

Tags: c#, ui-automation

We are working on UI Automation for the third party software. And we are firing button by the invoke method.

```
AutomationElement appElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, condition);
AutomationElement Addbutton = GetElementByNameProperty(appElement, "Add");
if (Addbutton != null)
{
  ClickElement(Addbutton);
}
```

Now i want to fire select all or (ctrl+A) command for selecting the element of the third party software. How to possible by UI automation? 
or
Can I fire command of some menu? for example (Edit> Select All). Can I fire select all command by the UI automation? 
Please help me.
thanks

Comment: What is the output type of your project? Win-App, console, library?

Comment: then how to possible by the UI automation using console app?

Comment: Can I fire command of some menu? for example (Edit> Select All). Can I fire select all command by the UI automation?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to automate sending the command Ctrl+A, you may want to check out the question below.  One of the suggestions is to use SendKeys and it works for me.

[How to send keys Control + A + B? (keep Control modifier "pressed")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902536/how-to-send-keys-control-a-b-keep-control-modifier-pressed)